# Ubuntu Won't Boot After Install on Samsung NP915S3G: error "All boot options are tried."

Tags: boot, windows, uefi, laptop, samsung

So yesterday I went ahead and bought the Samsung NP915S3G (ATIV Book 9 Lite) and installed Tahr in hope that everything would go smoothly. For the most part it; everything necessary seems to work off the bat. Unfortunately when I restart it, nothing boots. I erased Windows so that's obviously not an option, but the computer seems pretty dead certain that there's nothing there to boot. I think this might have a lot to do with UEFI which is a field I have next to no experience with. There also seems to be a fat32 partition that consistently reappears when I delete it.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.[image: The error displayed when trying to boot.]

Comment: reboot from installation USB or DVD and run Boot Repair.

Comment: You've probably got an EFI that's buggily refusing to boot anything but the Windows boot loader. [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) can fix this, although without more information, I can't be certain that's a suitable response. You might try running it anyhow, or using the [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) to generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to a pastebin site and post the URL to the document here for further analysis.

Comment: Unfortunately Boot Repair Disk doesn't seem to have any effect. Here's the BootInfo summary produced by it.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/7298587/

Answer (score 1):

Thats it working now guys, thanks for the help. I simply retried Boot Repair and ensured that "Separate /boot/efi partition" was ticked in the advanced options. This link was of great help.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Identifying_if_the_computer_boots_the_Ubuntu_DVD_in_EFI_mode

Is there a way to mark this as solved like things were in the forums? Or any other etiquette to follow?

Comment: Click the tick mark, next to an answer that solves your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your Samsung PC might be affected by the UEFI problem that Matthew Garrett mentions in his blog:

> "The problem with Samsung laptops bricking themselves turned out to be down to the UEFI variable store becoming more than 50% full [...]"
>   : http://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/23554.html

But there is a way to disable UEFI and use the legacy boot, which might solve your problem ([Source](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2417361,00.asp)):

1. (Since you erased Windows 8, I won't cover the steps required with a Windows 8 installation)
2. Boot your PC and press the bios key (in your case F2) repeatedly
3. If a startup menu is shown select *BIOS setup*
4. Locate the *Boot options* entry (Depending on your machine it may either be under *System configuration* or *Security* tab) and open it
5. In the *Boot options* menu, enable *Legacy Support*
6. (Optional) Change the Legacy boot order at the end of the page
7. Save the changes and reboot

Comment: No, the computer is not bricked. It's much more likely another problem.

Comment: I've found a post (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2192346) with a similar problem. The asker has tried installing Ubuntu with secure boot disabled. Maybe it works after disabling secure boot or following any other steps in the mentioned post..